# Draw a binary heap in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, drawing, binary-tree

I want to draw a max heap in MATLAB. But the software does not correctly positions the last node (please note that heap is a complete binary graph). I have a bunch of such heaps and want to correct the positions automatic. If there is any trick.

PS.
I have also used treeplot, but it suffers from the same shortcomming.

CODE:

```
f=figure(1);
clf
heap = sparse([1 2 2 3 3 4],[2 3 4 5 6 7],1,7,7);
bg = biograph(heap,{'H','2.0391(10,4)','1.9030(9,5)','1.2717(8,2)', '0.8532(7,3)', '1.9754(6,5)','1.9754(5,6)'});
g = biograph.bggui(bg);
```

Current output:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps changing the [layout type](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/bioinfo/ref/dolayoutbiograph.html) is relevant? Which things did you try and which docs did you read?

Comment: The matlab help and about 2 hours googling. I saw only three different layouts. but none of them works